# Fire react-native method from IntentService

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, intentservice

I am trying to implement a native geofencing solution for android and react-native. In this case, I have a Monitoring-Geofence that uses an IntentService to handle when the user moves out of this geofence. Then, an asynchronous react-native method should be fired, that recalculates the geofences.

So the basic problem is, how can I pass a react-native method/callback to an IntentService. I could only find solutions to add simple data to an intent with putExtra. Second question would be how to define the JS/react-native method, so that it can be triggered and run while App is in the background?

Comment: I guess what you would like to do is to have a listener for detecting when the user moves out of the geofence, then call the native method which recalculates the geofences.

Comment: Have you had a look at headless js?

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you need to access some part of the Java or ObjC coding, you need to create a native module. Basically you would create a basic project that uses the Java/Android code and make an interface for you to use in React Native.

See here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

Comment: That is totally clear and not part of the question. The question is when writing a native Android react-native module, how to pass an async JS callbacks to an IntentService so it can be triggered while the app is in background or even not running. My current approach is not to use a js callback, but an event that the react-native app can listen to.

Comment: The answer does not really help.

Comment: @10101010 Fair enough, thank you for explaining the downvote, something most people dont do around here.